# Ubuntu Touch and QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

I'm planning buying a tablet for running Ubuntu. There are little info on experience with Ubuntu Touch and QGIS and does it work? What I want is to run it on the tablet, drawing polygons etc on screen, but which version works best? Anyone that have good experiences? And no Windows is not an option, maybe as dualboot.

Comment: What kind of hardware is it?

Comment: Dual boot installed, but the development behind Ubuntu touch is still on a primitive stage. My advice is to stay on Ubuntu desktop. This was tested on Nexus 10, 2012 edition. Though limitations and lack of  the Python Plugins, check out QGIS for Android.